# Duplicate Corporate Sync Account "Null"

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, exchange, accounts

My organization just switched to the Droid Razr Maxx, one of the phones is having an issue with adding a corporate sync email account.  Whenever we try to add the account it says that it can't add because of duplicate account "Null".  I don't see this "Null" account anywhere, so i can't seem to remove it.  I'm not really sure what we can do, besides doing a reset and would only do that as a last course of action.  We are running android version 4 and using office 365 exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing Cache and Data for the following apps under `Settings -> Apps -> All` (tap on each app and then tap `Clear data` and `Clear cache` buttons where available):

- Email
- Exchange Services
- Google Account Manager

This should clear all the accounts (including the GMail one), and should allow you to add the Corporate account.